# Forcing IE11 to launch my pop up site in 64 bit

Tags: internet-explorer-11

So I have this issue, I have a web application that needs to open a popup in IE that is 64bit.

By default, it launches in 32bit. So I changed the 2 IE settings:

Trusted Sites -> Enable Protected Mode
Advanced Security -> Enable 64 bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode

When I navigate to my site, if i use IP address, or short hostname, it behaves as expected and launches in 64 bit. But if I launch my site with the FQDN xxxxx.domain.com it still launches in 32 bit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is your IE version and OS version? Is the manager process of IE 64 bit?

You could try the following methods:

1. **Enable UAC**

   If UAC is off, Enhanced Protected Mode doesn't do anything. You could enable UAC by editing the registry: Set **EnableLUA** value to **1** in the following path:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
   ```

   Or open the **Control Panel**, select **User Accounts**, click **Change User Account Control settings**, move the slider up, then click OK.
2. **Disable LCIE**

   By disabling LCIE, there will be only one process no matter how many tabs running in IE. If the main process is 64 bit, then you'll get a single 64 bit process for all the tabs. Save below code as a **reg file**, then double click it to make it work in registry:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] 

   "TabProcGrowth"="0" 

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] 

   "TabProcGrowth"="0" 

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] 

   "TabProcGrowth"="0"
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Works. But what is the reprocussion of #2?